# Android RTL password fields?

Tags: android

It appears that if you have an EditText on android with the

`android:inputType="textPassword"` or `android:password="true`

fields on them, right-to-left text does NOT appear right-to-left (stays left-to-right).

However without the password denotations the text does appear RTL.

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround?

Comment: FWIW, I do not see an issue filed for this at http://b.android.com.

Comment: I'll try on a few more devices before I report it

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For 17+ (4.2.x+) you can use [textAlignment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atextAlignment)

android:textAlignment="viewStart"

Comment: For 4.2.x+, yes. This still doesn't exist in the appcompat libraries, so if you want to do this in 2.3 or 4.0, you have to use the other solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me , I reported the issue at:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201471&q=rtl%20password&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: Almost worked. For me it displays everything fine, It just places the cursor after the hint when in left to right layout

Comment: Switching this to the answer now that 4.2+ has taken majority.

Comment: It's worth to mention that this requires having `android:supportsRtl="true"` on `<application>` element in the app manifest.

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I've found was to set the gravity programatically to LEFT or RIGHT after setting the inputType.

Comment: You might consider to add the question as comment to your answer.

Comment: Yep. This ended up being the only way.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was simply solved by changing the `layout_width` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: You can set alignment text of EditText (Password field) with setting one property in XML file:

extAlignment=viewStart

Answer (score 1):

If you put inputType = textPassword or set a passwordTransformation method on EditText, text direction is taken as LTR. It means RTL for password is discouraged. You need to write custom TextView to override this behaviour.

Code snippet from android source for TextView.

```
// PasswordTransformationMethod always have LTR text direction heuristics returned by
        // getTextDirectionHeuristic, needs reset
        mTextDir = getTextDirectionHeuristic();


protected TextDirectionHeuristic getTextDirectionHeuristic() {
        if (hasPasswordTransformationMethod()) {
            // passwords fields should be LTR
            return TextDirectionHeuristics.LTR;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In My Case both worked fine.

1) android:textAlignment="viewStart"

And

2)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291472/6493661

Answer (score 1):

and the right answer is:

```
RtlEditText mUserPassword = root.findViewById(R.id.register_fragment_password);
mUserPassword.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

creating our own EditText!

it work prefectly only if you replace the dot with astrix by AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod below this code.

```
public class RtlEditText extends EditText {


public RtlEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RtlEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RtlEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public RtlEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public TextDirectionHeuristic getTextDirectionHeuristic() {
        // passwords fields should be LTR
        return TextDirectionHeuristics.ANYRTL_LTR;
}}



public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
@Override
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
    return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
}

private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private CharSequence mSource;
    public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
        mSource = source; // Store char sequence
    }
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return '*'; // This is the important part
    }
    public int length() {
        return mSource.length(); // Return default
    }
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just create an custom editText and add this code:**

```
@Override
   public TextDirectionHeuristic getTextDirectionHeuristic() {
           // passwords fields should be LTR
           return TextDirectionHeuristics.ANYRTL_LTR;
     }
```

**Full class example:**

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {


   public CustomEditText(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public CustomEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public CustomEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

   @Override
   public TextDirectionHeuristic getTextDirectionHeuristic() {
           // passwords fields should be LTR
           return TextDirectionHeuristics.ANYRTL_LTR;
     }
}
```