# Password edittext hint text alignment on right side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm facing an issue that when I define an `EditText` as `password` type and view my screen in Arabic language the password field hint text is showing on the left side instead of right side [that is expected].

[image: issue]

Above is the result I get. I need password hint text to be starting from the right side that's where Arabic writings start. I've also tried adding text gravity to it but no luck.

Comment: Use  `android:gravity="right"`  or  `android:textDirection="rtl"`

Comment: please share your code so that changes can be made

Comment: fixed already thanks everyone. i added this line and it fixed android:textAlignment="viewStart"

Comment: @UsmanGhauri Can you please show how you did it? It doesn't work for me. Instead, I had to add `\u202B` into the RTL text, and only then it aligned fine. Wrote about it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124606481

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to this post :
[Android RTL password fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838216/android-rtl-password-fields)

For API 17+ you can use

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Comment: yes just saw related answer. and thanks its working

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="كلمة المرور"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Comment: This is for one case only. What i needed to achieve was i wanted to shift rtl on signup page i.e. If user select arabic it shows layouts in Arabic and if selected in English show English layouts. Setting gravity to right will fix one issue and will create another in English view. I know you'll suggest me to create one layout for Arabic and one for English but thats duplication. im just using strings english and AR and letting the android framework do the trick of rtl shift